# How can i change Foreach Loop Recurse Property Dynamically

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I'm working in project where sometimes i need to loop through sub-folder and some time i don't. In order to achieve my gaol i want to use single Foreach Loop and dynamically changing it's property **Traverse Subfolder**
If there any solution available to change properties dynamically by SSIS Task Expression or through VB or C# code or any thing?
Please help.

[image]

Comment: whats your data flow task within container  ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered having two copies of the Foreach Loop, one with traverse subfolders checked and the other with this property unchecked, then using a precedence constraint with a parameter to decide which one to execute?  Each Foreach loop could be connected to the preceding Execute SQL Task in your example with a precedence constraint on each that contains an expression that checks a parameter to determine with Foreach Loop to use.  The example below is the expression on a precedence constraint that uses a Boolean parameter.  This would be on the Foreach Loop that traverses subfolders, and the same would apply to the other (non-recursive) Foreach Loop with checking for the parameter set to false instead.

```
@[$Package::TraverseSubFolders] == True
```

Answer (score 2):

Under expressions in the foreach loop Collection properties you're after the one called "Recurse"

[image]

Create a boolean variable and then assign the variable to the "Recurse" property.
You may have to set the delay validation property to true on the foreach loop.

Then flip that variable at run-time to change it's behavior using a script task or could be done with results from a stored procedure.

Comment: got it
Thank you so much